# What is () in Haskell, exactly?

Tags: haskell, types, unit-type

I'm reading *Learn You a Haskell*, and in the monad chapters, it seems to me that `()` is being treated as a sort of "null" for every type. When I check the type of `()` in GHCi, I get

```
>> :t ()
() :: ()
```

which is an extremely confusing statement. It seems that `()` is a type all to itself. I'm confused as to how it fits into the language, and how it seems to be able to stand for any type.

Comment: It's the `Unit` type. It has exactly one value. . Actions which return no interesting values it.

Comment: A type with exactly one non-bottom value.

Comment: What is a bottom value?

Comment: @Maksim: Bottom value is a value belonging to all types. It usually denotes that no other value has been returned (nontermination of function, exception etc.)

Comment: Strange that no answer mentions category theory here...

Comment: yes, unit is terminal object and void is initial object.

Comment: Similar to how `Bool` is a type containing only two values, `Unit` is a type containing only one value, `()`.

So where C has functions that state their return-type as `void` [not *really* a type, but a dummy-keyword meaning "there is no return-value"], the more consistent approach is "there *is* a return-value, but it's totally uninteresting" -- `()`.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

**tl;dr** `()` does not add a "null" value to every type, hell no; `()` is a "dull" value in a type of its own: `()`.

Let me step back from the question a moment and address a common source of confusion. A key thing to absorb when learning Haskell is the distinction between its *expression* language and its *type* language. You're probably aware that the two are kept separate. But that allows the same symbol to be used in both, and that is what is going on here. There are simple textual cues to tell you which language you're looking at. You don't need to parse the whole language to detect these cues.

The top level of a Haskell module lives, by default, in the expression language. You define functions by writing equations between expressions. But when you see *foo* :: *bar* in the expression language, it means that *foo* is an expression and *bar* is its type. So when you read `() :: ()`, you're seeing a statement which relates the `()` in the expression language with the `()` in the type language. The two `()` symbols mean different things, because they are not in the same language. This replication often causes confusion for beginners, until the expression/type language separation installs itself in their subconscious, at which point it becomes helpfully mnemonic.

The keyword `data` introduces a new datatype declaration, involving a careful mixture of the expression and type languages, as it says first what the new type is, and secondly what its values are.

```
data TyCon tyvar ... tyvar = ValCon1 type ... type |  ...  | ValConn type ... type
```

In such a declaration, type constructor *TyCon* is being added to the type language and the *ValCon* value constructors are being added to the expression language (and its pattern sublanguage). In a `data` declaration, the things which stand in argument places for the *ValCon*s tell you the types given to the arguments when that *ValCon* is used in expressions. For example,

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

declares a type constructor `Tree` for binary tree types storing `a` elements at nodes, whose values are given by value constructors `Leaf` and `Node`. I like to colour type constructors (`Tree`) blue and value constructors (`Leaf`, `Node`) red. There should be no blue in expressions and (unless you're using advanced features) no red in types. The built-in type `Bool` could be declared,

```
data Bool = True | False
```

adding blue `Bool` to the type language, and red `True` and `False` to the expression language. Sadly, my markdown-fu is inadequate to the task of adding the colours to this post, so you'll just have to learn to add the colours in your head.

The "unit" type uses `()` as a special symbol, but it works as if declared

```
data () = ()  -- the left () is blue; the right () is red
```

meaning that a notionally blue `()` is a type constructor in the type language, but that a notionally red `()` is a value constructor in the expression language, and indeed `() :: ()`. [ It is not the only example of such a pun. The types of larger tuples follow the same pattern: pair syntax is as if given by

```
data (a, b) = (a, b)
```

adding `(,)` to both type and expression languages. But I digress.]

So the type `()`, often pronounced "Unit", is a type containing one value worth speaking of: that value is also written `()` but in the *expression* language, and is sometimes pronounced "void". A type with only one value is not very interesting. A value of type `()` contributes zero bits of information: you already know what it must be. So, while there is nothing special about type `()` to indicate side effects, it often shows up as the value component in a monadic type. Monadic operations tend to have types which look like

```
val-in-type-1 -> ... -> val-in-type-n -> effect-monad val-out-type
```

where the return type is a type application: the (type) function tells you which *effects* are possible and the (type) argument tells you what sort of *value* is produced by the operation. For example

```
put :: s -> State s ()
```

which is read (because application associates to the left ["as we all did in the sixties", Roger Hindley]) as

```
put :: s -> (State s) ()
```

has one value input type `s`, the effect-monad `State s`, and the value output type `()`. When you see `()` as a value output type, that just means "this operation is used only for its *effect*; the value delivered is uninteresting". Similarly

```
putStr :: String -> IO ()
```

delivers a string to `stdout` but does not return anything exciting.

The `()` type is also useful as an element type for *container*-like structures, where it indicates that the data consists just of a *shape*, with no interesting payload. For example, if `Tree` is declared as above, then `Tree ()` is the type of binary tree shapes, storing nothing of interest at nodes. Similarly `[()]` is the type of lists of dull elements, and if there is nothing of interest in a list's elements, then the only information it contributes is its length.

To sum up, `()` is a type. Its one value, `()`, happens to have the same name, but that's ok because the type and expression languages are separate. It's useful to have a type representing "no information" because, in context (e.g., of a monad or a container), it tells you that only the context is interesting.

Comment: Sadly, there is no way to use color besides the default syntax highlighting. If you use HTML, you can use italics and bold, e.g. `<pre>data <b>Bool</b> = <i>True</i> | <i>False</i></pre>`, but I fear that's the best you can do given the limitations of SO's markdown. The alternative would be to use images.

Comment: It's tempting to replace the monochrome declarations with coloured images, but my long term objective is to persuade people to perceive the colour even in its absence.

Comment: Do people actually call red-`()` "void"? That seems wrong, as "void" would be the absence of _any_ values to me.

Comment: Some do, especially if they learned ML before Haskell, as I did. Your intuition about connations seem sound to me, but you should address them to the C people! If Void were a type (see Data.Void) we might hope it had zero values (which is why I called it Zero when I suggested it). However, the void *value* should similarly be a value which contains no information. And that's the situation. Set theorists have a similar situation, where the empty set is also the only possible (hence dull) element of the unit set.

Comment: Randomly stumbled across this and found this _extremely_ clarifying, thanks!

Comment: Super Haskell n00b here (I'm but a mere Swift dev), I wonder if anyone could explain the syntax of the constructor of "data Tree a = Leaf | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)", in LearnYouaHaskell I only found record syntax, but it is very different from this Tree aboce. More specifically I wonder what "(Tree a) a (Tree a)" means. I guess it means that a Node can have two parents? http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses

Comment: @Sajjon `Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)` means the Node has two children, not two parents :) Each child is also a tree (it's a recursive data type)

Answer (score 34):

The `()` type can be thought of as a zero-element tuple.  It's a type that can only have one value, and thus it's used where you need to have a type, but you don't actually need to convey any information.  Here's a couple of uses for this.

Monadic things like `IO` and `State` have a return value, as well as performing side-effects.  Sometimes the only point of the operation is to perform a side-effect, like writing to the screen or storing some state.  For writing to the screen, `putStrLn` must have type `String -> IO ?` -- `IO` always has to have some return type, but here there's nothing useful to return.  So what type should we return?  We could say Int, and always return 0, but that's misleading.  So we return `()`, the type that has only one value (and thus no useful information), to indicate that there's nothing useful coming back.

It's sometimes useful to have a type which can have no useful values.  Consider if you'd implemented a type `Map k v` which maps keys of type `k` to values of type `v`.  Then you want to implement a `Set`, which is really similar to a map except that you don't need the value part, just the keys.  In a language like Java you might use booleans as the dummy value type, but really you just want a type that has no useful values.  So you could say `type Set k = Map k ()`

It should be noted that `()` is not particularly magic.  If you want you can store it in a variable and do a pattern match on it (although there's not much point):

```
main = do
  x <- putStrLn "Hello"
  case x of
    () -> putStrLn "The only value..."
```

Answer (score 14):

It is called the `Unit` type, usually used to represent side effects. You can think of it vaguely as `Void` in Java. Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type) and [here](http://james-iry.blogspot.de/2009/07/void-vs-unit.html) etc. What can be confusing is that `()` syntactically represents both the type and its only value literal. Also note that it is not similar to `null` in Java which means an undefined reference - `()` is just effectively a 0-sized tuple.

Comment: I should add that it's not only the `Unit` type, but also literal representing the only value of this type.

Answer (score 11):

I really like to think of `()` by analogy with tuples.

`(Int, Char)` is the type of all pairs of an `Int` and a `Char`, so it's values are all possible values of `Int` crossed with all possible values of `Char`. `(Int, Char, String)` is similarly the type of all triples of an `Int`, a `Char`, and a `String`.

It's easy to see how to keep extending this pattern upwards, but what about downwards?

`(Int)` would be the "1-tuple" type, consisting of all possible values of `Int`. But that would be parsed by Haskell as just putting parentheses around `Int`, and thus being just the type `Int`. And values in this type would be `(1)`, `(2)`, `(3)`, etc, which also would just get parsed as ordinary `Int` values in parentheses. But if you think about it, a "1-tuple" is exactly the same as just a single value, so there's no need to actually have them exist.

Going down one step further to zero-tuples gives us `()`, which should be all possible combinations of values in an empty list of types. Well, there's exactly one way to do that, which is to contain no other values, so there should be only one value in the type `()`. And by analogy with tuple value syntax, we can write that value as `()`, which certainly *looks* like a tuple containing no values.

That's exactly how it works. There is no magic, and this type `()` and its value `()` are in no way treated specially by the language.

`()` is not in fact being treated as "a null value for any type" in the monads examples in the LYAH book. Whenever the type `()` is used the *only* value which can be returned is `()`. So it's used as a type to *explicitly* say that there **cannot be** any other return value. And likewise where another type is supposed to be returned, you *cannot* return `()`.

The thing to keep in mind is that when a bunch of monadic computations are composed together with `do` blocks or operators like `>>=`, `>>`, etc, they'll be building a value of type `m a` for some monad `m`. That choice of `m` has to stay the same throughout the component parts (there's no way to compose a `Maybe Int` with an `IO Int` in that way), but the `a` can and very often is different at each stage.

So when someone sticks an `IO ()` in the middle of an `IO String` computation, that's not using the `()` as a null in the `String` type, it's simply *using* an `IO ()` on the way to building an `IO String`, the same way you could *use* an `Int` on the way to building a `String`.

Answer (score 7):

Yet another angle:

`()` is the name of a set which contains a single element called `()`.

Its indeed slightly confusing that the name of the set and the 
element in it happens to be the same in this case.

Remember: in Haskell a type is a set that has its possible values as elements in it.

Answer (score 6):

The confusion comes from other programming languages:
"void" means in most imperative languages that there is no structure in memory storing a value. It seems inconsistent because "boolean" has 2 values instead of 2 bits, while "void" has no bits instead of no values, but there it is about *what* a function returns in a practical sense. To be exact: its single value consumes no bit of storage.

Let's ignore the value bottom (written `_|_`) for a moment...

`()` is called Unit, written like a null-tuple. It has only one value. And it is not called 
`Void`, because [`Void`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/void/0.6/doc/html/Data-Void.html#t:Void) has not even any value, thus could not be returned by any function.

---

Observe this: `Bool` has 2 values (`True` and `False`), `()` has one value (`()`), and [`Void`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/void/0.6/doc/html/Data-Void.html#t:Void) has no value (it doesn't exist). They are like sets with two/one/no elements. The least memory they need to store their value is 1 bit / no bit / impossible, respectively. Which means that a function that returns a `()` may return with a result value (the obvious one) that may be useless to you. `Void` on the other hand would imply that that function will never return and never give you any result, because there would not exist any result.

If you want to give "that value" a name, that a function returns which never returns (yes, this sounds like crazytalk), then call it bottom ("`_|_`", written like a reversed T). It could represent an exception or infinity loop or deadlock or "just wait longer". (Some functions will only then return bottom, iff one of their parameters is bottom.)

When you create the cartesian product / a tuple of these types, you will observe the same behaviour:
    `(Bool,Bool,Bool,(),())` has 2·2·2·1·1=6 differnt values. `(Bool,Bool,Bool,(),Void)` is like the set {t,f}×{t,f}×{t,f}×{u}×{} which has 2·2·2·1·0=0 elements, unless you count `_|_` as a value.