# what is the type () :: () in haskell means?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

on the prelude i just checked the type of () what does it really mean

```
Prelude> :type ()
() :: ()
```

I know you can return this from a function when you don't want to do any thing. what actually is happening there ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Different namespaces

As said by Lee, `()` happens to be both the name of a type, and of its only constructor. Basically, it's the same as if you had defined

```
data Unit = Unit

f :: Unit -> Int
f Unit = 7
```

...perhaps less confusing when the constructor isn't nullary:

```
newtype MyInt = MyInt Int

g :: MyInt -> Int
g (MyInt i) = i
```

Note that in each case, both of the “equal” names live in completely seperate namespaces: read the examples as

```
data TʏᴘᴇSᴄᴏᴘᴇ.Unit = VᴀʟᴜᴇSᴄᴏᴘᴇ.Unit
newtype TʏᴘᴇSᴄᴏᴘᴇ.MyInt = VᴀʟᴜᴇSᴄᴏᴘᴇ.MyInt Int

VᴀʟᴜᴇSᴄᴏᴘᴇ.MyInt 7 :: TʏᴘᴇSᴄᴏᴘᴇ.MyInt
VᴀʟᴜᴇSᴄᴏᴘᴇ.Unit :: TʏᴘᴇSᴄᴏᴘᴇ.Unit
VᴀʟᴜᴇSᴄᴏᴘᴇ.() :: TʏᴘᴇSᴄᴏᴘᴇ.()
```

### About the unit type

Your characterisation

> I know you can return this from a function when you don't want to do any thing

is kind of correct from a procedural point of view, but in Haskell “do anything” isn't really a meaningful thing to say: functions *never* “do anything”, they merely yield results. And a function with result type `()` is no exception: it yields a result, only the result contains no actual information.

For further reference, see [What is () in Haskell, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892570/what-is-in-haskell-exactly).

Answer (score 3):

`()` (pronounced unit) is both the name of the type and the single value of that type. It is therefore saying 'The value `()` has type `()`' in the same way as

```
:t "Hello"
"Hello" :: String
```