# Instancing arbitrary

Tags: haskell, instance

I'm having trouble writing an instance of Arbitrary for my data type. Which is the following:

```
    data FavoriteList a = FL [(a, Bool)] deriving Eq
```

This is what I have:

```
    instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary(FavoriteList a) where
       arbitrary = oneof [liftM FavoriteList arbitrary]
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
    Not in scope: data constructor 'FavoriteList'
```

I'm probably not understanding something about types and constructors I think...Can someone help me out?

Comment: i am not sure if this is correct, but can you try `oneof [liftM FL arbitrary]` ?

Comment: I would've expected just `liftM FL arbitrary` to work, without any need for `oneof`?

Comment: I got this 'Not in scope: data constructor FL'

Comment: You need to export it from the module defining it and import it in the module defining the instance.

Comment: Isn't a 'import FavoriteList' enough? @AlexeyRomanov

Comment: No. You need to import `FL` as well. `import FavoriteList(FL)` or `import FavoriteList(..)` (and same for export).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to use the type-level term `FavoriteList` at the value-level. `FL` is the value-level term that constructs a value of type `FavoriteList a` for whatever `a` you choose. `FL <$> arbitrary` should be sufficient, or equivalently `fmap FL arbitrary` or `liftM FL arbitrary`. For a more thorough explanation of Haskell's type- and value-level languages, see [this excellent answer by Conor McBride](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16893900/2225384).